# Download file instead showing it it new tab

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to download file by using AJAX. Now my code after succes submit open PDF file in new tab. How can I change my code to run automatic download?
This is my code below:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/templates/mywebsite/save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataArray,
            success: function(response)
            {

                window.open('/upload/myfile.pdf','_blank');

                }

        });
```

Comment: Instead of linking the PDF file directly use PHP with headers to force download the PDF file.

Comment: can you explain how can I do this? I don't really know PHP

Comment: Create PHP file with the following code and save as download.php,

`<?php
// save this PHP file as download.php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="PDF_FILE_NAME.pdf"'); // when the user downloads the file the PDF file will be downloaded with this name
readfile('PATH_TO_YOUR_PDF_FILE.PDF');
?>`

Comment: And in your ajax, change `window.open('/upload/myfile.pdf','_blank');` to `window.open('download.php','_blank');`

Comment: why pdf file open as blank page?